# Dynamically arrange application windows on top of each other in linux

Tags: c++, bash, gnome

I want to dynamically using a bash script/c++ code arrange windows that are present on the desktop on top of each other .I know the name of the applications whose windows will be present on the gnome desktop.

Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Check these out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiling_window_manager#Third_party_tiling_applications_on_Xorg

Comment: I don't want tiling , i want the applications to be on top of each other

Comment: Linux is a kernel. Your question is about desktop environments. There are many desktop environments that run on top of  Unix-like operating systems. There's no common answer for all DEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [Devil's Pie](http://burtonini.com/blog/computers/devilspie). This is a window-matching utility that was especially written for the Metacity window manager, IIRC. It allows you to execute custom actions for certain types of windows. In your case, you could simply match *all* windows and set their respective positions/geometries (I don't know the manual of Devil's Pie by heart, but I am pretty sure that it can do this).

There's also a successor, called [Devil's Pie 2](http://www.gusnan.se/devilspie2/), which uses Lua-based rules. However, I don't have any further information about it.